# Can't update Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1703

So for the last couple of months I can't update my windows 10. I've been stuck in a cycle where I just ignore the Update for about a week, then the computer forces me to update but during the update it fails and goes back to previous version. Did anyone experience a similar problem and if yes how did you fix it?

Comment: Mount the current Windows 10 ISO and install the upgrade that way.

Comment: @Ramhound okay and how do I do that?

Comment: Windows 10 has the ability to mount ISOs built in.  Just mount the current ISO and run the installer

Comment: @Ramhound and where do I get the ISO?

Comment: The Microsoft website.  There is an existing question that provides more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this. The problem was with drivers. I installed a program called [Driver Easy](https://www.drivereasy.com/) and I updated my drivers (there were a lot of devices with outdated drivers) and now it works fine.